# Serve wordpress in nginx subdirectory along with spring boot

Tags: wordpress, spring-boot, nginx

I have a Spring Boot application with nginx as reverse proxy in front of it, and it's working perfectly. I would like to serve in `/blog` a wordpress application. I have tried every tutorial and post that I found on the internet about serving a wordpress in a subdirectory but I'm still having issues.

**I'm getting a "File not found." error every time I try to access to `/blog` path.**

Here is my configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_buffer_size 128k;
                proxy_buffers 4 256k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        }

        location /blog {
                alias /root/wordpress;
                index index.php;

                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
                }
        }
}
```

Also the nginx error.log says the following:

```
2021/07/26 20:32:11 [error] 21503#21503: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.94.12.53, server: example.com, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?